# Adhesive removal from Bruce flooring

Tags: engineered-flooring

We have Bruce engineered hardwood flooring installed by a previous homeowner. At some point double-sided tape was used to hold down an area rug. I have tried to remove the tape by carefully pulling it up. The tape came up but the adhesive remains. I have a sample of the flooring and can see that it has a thin veneer (1/16") with a thin protective clearcoat over it.
I'm concerned about using anything harsh such as Goof Off or nail polish remover that might remove the clearcoat and damage the veneer.
What's the best way to approach this in removing the adhesive?

Comment: You might want to contact Bruce and see if they have any recommendations.

Comment: I have. They haven't been much help. I think liability concerns. I just sent them another request for better info but haven't heard back. I'm hoping someone on Stack Exchange may have some hands-on experience.

Comment: Maybe you can convince a salesperson, or installer to give you some samples to experiment on.

Comment: For removing beer bottle label adhesive   i soak the bottles in bath of water and oxy-clean overnight and it slides right off easily with a kitchen scrubber sponge.

Comment: @Alaska Man - Thanks. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Goof off is really not that strong, I use Remove-it contractors grade citrus cleaner. I have found it is great at removing adhesive goo. Non toxic and even works well on mastic , both on hands and surfaces.

I use double sided tape for name plates on load centers, I have to update these when modifications are made I use dental floss to cut the foam then Remove-it and the goo wipes off sometimes a second spray is needed on larger areas but it has always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know if it works.